# Is there a beginners tutorial for Wolfram Engine users?

Tags: guidelines, free-wolfram-engine

I was taking a look at WolframEngine. The fact that it is freely available, virtually making Wolfram tools and language accessible to anybody is very much attractive!
Nevertheless, the first impact when running the SW is pretty awful.
Is there any beginners guide?
I find it rather not so intuitive. For instance, is there a possibility to write down scripts and run them as if they were nb?
I tried plotting a simple function with Plot[] and it returned a rather funny message:

> -Graphics-

What was it trying to tell me?

Comment: It's just like Mathematica but without the frontend. For a more intuitive experience, especially if you're coming from Mathematica, use the [Jupyter notebook interface](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter). It will display graphics as you would expect. The terminal cannot display graphics, but you can export the graphics using the `Export` command. `-Graphics-` is just telling you that the output is graphic.

Comment: "Nevertheless, the first impact when running the SW is pretty awful." - now you know how it's like to use *Mathematica* from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question. However, if you still want to bring similar experience like Mathematica notebook to Wolfram Engine, try to use [WLJS Notebook](https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend)

Comment: WLJS does not work for me under macOS 14.0 -- neither the Electron cross-platform app nor the console/web-browser combination. I do have WolframEngine installed and activated with Wolfram; I also have wolframscript and Mathematica. With fomer after all the downloading aftrer i open the app, I get a totally blank window in which I see nothing and can type nothing; with the console/browser combination, after wolframscript -f Scripts/run.wlsI see af binary write error and then the indicated browser URL cannot be opened.